# TicTacToe Python assistance

Tags: python

For my assignment I have to get this tic tac toe program to work by implementing the successor function and all necessary helper function. At its current state the board is drawn, however you cannot see the X's and O's nor can you play the game. Can anyone help me/explain about the successor function?

```
# A *cell* is an integer in the interval [1,10). Cells represent squares
# on the tic tac toe board as pictured below:
#    1|2|3
#    -----
#    4|5|6
#    -----
#    7|8|9
#
# A *game state* is a pair (aka 2-tuple) of the form (S,T) where S and T
# are sets of cells. The game state (S,T) is thought of as the
# configuration in which S is the set of cells occupied by 'X' and T is
# the set of cells occupied by 'O'. For example, the game state ({1,9},{5})
# may be visualized as follows:
#    x| |
#    -----
#     |o|
#    -----
#     | |x

def initialState():
    return (set(),set())

def displayImages(S):
    return background() + cellContents(S)

def background():
    L1 = (200,0,200,600)
    L2 = (400,0,400,600)
    L3 = (0,200,600,200)
    L4 = (0,400,600,400)
    return [L1, L2, L3, L4]

def cellContents(S):
    contents = []
    for cell in S[0]:
        contents.append(cellText("X",cell))
    for cell in S[1]:
        contents.append(cellText("O",cell))
    return contents

def cellText(P,C):
    (x,y) = cellCenter(C)
    return (P,x,y,18)

def cellCenter(C):
    if C == 1:
        return (100,500)
    elif C == 2:
        return (300,500)
    elif C == 3:
        return (500,500)
    elif C == 4:
        return (100,300)
    elif C == 5:
        return (300,300)
    elif C == 6:
        return (500,300)
    elif C == 7:
        return (100,100)
    elif C == 8:
        return (300,100)
    else:
        return (500,100)

def successor(S,P):
    return S

# TPGE GAME ENGINE

from graphics import *

# displaySize() is the size of the display window, (width, height)

def displaySize() :
    return (600,600)

# If x is an image, imageKind(x) is the type of image x is:
# 'circle', 'text', or 'lineSegment'

def imageKind(x):
    if len(x)==3 : return 'circle'
    elif type(x[0])== str :return 'text'
    else : return 'lineSegment'

# If x is an image, convert(x) is the corresponding image in the
# graphics.py library. We turn the screen upside down so that the origin
# is in the lower left corner, so it matches what they learn in algebra
# class.

def convert(x):
    if imageKind(x) == 'circle':
        return convertCircle(x)
    elif imageKind(x) == 'lineSegment':
        return convertLine(x)
    elif imageKind(x) == 'text':
        return convertText(x)


def convertLine(x):
    (W,H) = displaySize()
    P1 = Point(x[0],H - x[1])
    P2 = Point(x[2],H - x[3])
    return Line(P1,P2)

def convertText(x):
    (W,H) = displaySize()
    center = Point(x[1],H-x[2])
    string = x[0]
    size = x[3]
    T = Text(center,string)
    T.setSize(size)
    return T

def convertCircle(x):
    (W,H) = displaySize()
    center = Point(x[0],H-x[1])
    radius = x[2]
    return Circle(center,radius)

# Create a window to play in

display = GraphWin("My game", displaySize()[0], displaySize()[1])

# The main loop
#
# Set the state, draw the display, get a mouse click, set the new state,
# and repeat until the user closes the window.

S = initialState()
images = [convert(x) for x in displayImages(S)]
while(True):
    for x in images: x.draw(display)
    c = display.getMouse()
    click = (c.getX(),displaySize()[1] - c.getY())
    S = successor(S,click)
    for I in images: I.undraw()
    images = [convert(x) for x in displayImages(S)]
```

Comment: @ritesh I don't see any problem with this question. Although it is homework-help, he has a legitimate question that will produce good answers. The fact that it is for an assignment does not make it 'not welcome'.

Answer (score 1):

`successor` takes two arguments: one is the game state, one is the spot just clicked. The game state is explained in the comments:

```
# A *game state* is a pair (aka 2-tuple) of the form (S,T) where S and T
# are sets of cells. The game state (S,T) is thought of as the
# configuration in which S is the set of cells occupied by 'X' and T is
# the set of cells occupied by 'O'. For example, the game state ({1,9},{5})
# may be visualized as follows:
```

`successor` takes the *current* state, and the location that the player has just clicked - and has to create and return the *new* game state. So, it knows what the board currently looks like, it knows which spot the player just chose, and it has to put an X or an O there.

Since the state is composed os S and T, it might be a bit confusing to have the state also called S, so let's start by renaming it and extracting the S and T from it:

```
def successor(state, position):
    S, T = state
```

now, the position is already in the form you want - you just need to *add* it to either the set of X positions or the set of O positions. For now, let's always add it to the set of X positions - this isn't exactly what you ultimately want it to achieve, but it should help you to understand what this function is *doing* and then you can improve it later.

```
def successor(state, position):
    S, T = state
    S.add(position)
```

and now we've created a new state, we need to return it:

```
def successor(state, position):
    S, T = state
    S.add(position)
    return S, T
```

with those three lines, what you should see is every time you click a square, it will put an X in it. The next step for you to work on would be to update this function so that it alternates between putting an X or putting an O.